# How often should I request a token when communicating with a third-party API?

Tags: c#, api-design, web-api, asp.net-mvc-web-api

I have an ASP.net web API. I would like to call another API that has an authentication token inside my API.

The code flow is as follows:

My API is called → Get authentication token from 3rd party API → Call the desired methods from 3rd party API.

The thing I can't decide is if my API is called 100 times, I will make 100 calls for the `GetToken()` method and another 100 for the desired method in the 3rd party API, which seems like an overhead and waste of time. Should I implement a logic in order to check if the token is still available?

Comment: It depends on the application, and how critical it is. What happens when there is a bug: just a few hundred of US$ lost, or many human lifes killed? IS your application driving a neurosurgery robot, or just a website selling candies?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The third party API may use a well-known mechanism, such as OAuth 2, for authentication. In OAuth 2, the token is generated once, and is used for multiple requests, until it expires. The expiration policy depends on the actual configuration of the service, and the way you interact with it (because of the sliding expiration and absolute expiration).

In this case, you make your job more complicated than it needs to be. Instead of implementing yourself the handling of the token, grab an existent OAuth 2 library (or whatever else is used by the API). The library will hide  the underlying complexity, including the generation of the token, and its renewal: you will have to give it the client ID and the password, and it will handle the remaining part. It is useful to understand what is happening under the hood (mostly because a possibly *leaky abstraction*, as well as for your own personal curiosity), but not absolutely necessary at the beginning.

If, instead, the API uses a home-grown mechanism:

- Contact the company, asking them if they plan to move to a more standard approach. Usually, home-grown mechanisms are insecure, badly designed, and poorly maintained. Moving to an API from a different company may be an alternative that you need to consider.
- If there is no plan to move to anything standard and you can't pick another API provider, ask the company if they can at least give you a client library for your language of choice. Often they do, which saves you a lot of work.
- If they can't provide any client library, consult their documentation. It should specify how often can you request a new token. Sometimes, requesting a token at every request would be against the policy, and you'll end up banned if you do so.

If there is no documentation, you should *really* move to another API provider. Using an undocumented API, with no support, and home-grown authentication is plain wrong.

Comment: Thank you, I have no idea about OAuth. Any resource that you can share according to my situation would be great.